# lookaside.fbsbx.com attachment link from private messages doesn't work

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cdn, attachment, instagram-api

I use the endpoint page-id/conversations?platform=instagram to get Instagram's private messages and i get attachment.
But the field : `attachment{image_data}` return me the image url in https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ however Instagram use https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/ for media.

How to get the valid resource url ? with access_token in url parameters ??

Have a good day !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it was a bug which is now fixed
-> https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1004663983788738/